# c# adding or deleting data in listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a program and i want to remove the data when i click double to any data.
How can i do that?
This is the part of my code:

```
this.listBox1.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(listBox1_MouseDoubleClick);



void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = this.listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            if (index != System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
                listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location));

            }
        }
```

Comment: Other than changing t he Remove(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location)) to RemoveAt(index), I am not sure what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Remove()` method needs the object which you want to remove as a parameter. To use an index use the `RemoveAt()` method:

```
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
```